# Root access to blank optical media

Tags: nautilus, dvd, cd, brasero, optical

Ubuntu seems to have a problem accessing blank optical media using sudo/root.

**Correct operation**

Insert a blank CD/DVD in the optical drive.
Open a terminal window.
Run `nautilus`
You should see a listing on the left for "Blank DVD+R Disc" with an eject button. This is the correct operation I expect.
Close the nautilus window.

Ensure nautilus is closed. It may require a ^c in the terminal window, or a `killall nautilus` command, because sometimes nautilus can be stubborn.

**Problem Demonstration**

Insert a blank CD/DVD in the optical drive.
Open a terminal window.
Run `sudo nautilus` and enter your password.
There is no listing for the blank disk!

This same problem can be demonstrated using other programs. Brasero is a perfect example. When you execute `brasero` from a terminal window and select "Data Disc", the default destination is the blank disk in the optical drive. When you perform the same procedure using `sudo brasero`, the blank optical disk is not an option, and the only choice is an Image File.

I get the same behavior when using a blank CD instead of a DVD, and when performing the same steps on multiple different systems. This problem seems to be present on a variety of different installations and versions. Primarily, I am using 16.04 LTS, which shows the same issue on three different computers/installations. I also tested the same issue on a 12.04 installation and the same problem is present.

I have been through all the troubleshooting steps I have found in various forums, with nothing seeming to work to correct the problem. All permissions have been thoroughly checked, and group configurations tested. The standard users can successfully burn blank disks, but the root user cannot.

Interestingly, `gnome-disks` does seem to correctly list the optical drive and detect the correct blank media, whether it is run using sudo or not.

Is this a bug that has been unnoticed for this long because of an odd use case? Does anyone have suggestions to correct this problem? I don't understand how the root user can be blocked where the individual users work correctly.

Comment: root is generally not part of the 'cdrom' group, thus hasn't access.  (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo dbus-launch nautilus
sudo dbus-launch brasero
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dbus-launch.1.html